# Telegraf send an image from Telegram API

Tags: javascript, bots, telegram, telegraf

I have a problem with getting an image from Telegram API (using telegraf javascript).

So I got the `json data` by `file_id` and if I try to send a photo using `ctx.replyWithPhoto('https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<TOKEN>/<PATH>')`

In cmd it shows next error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 400: Bad Request: there is no photo in the request

But if I try to put other image with different url, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Which method are you using `getFile` or `getFileLink`? If you use `getFileLink` method, it returns the primary link to the file. So you can reuse it.